# SqlDependency on .netcore3.1 service

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, sqldependency, broker

I have a little problem. When I use SqlDependency on .NetCore service app after 30 seconds throw SqlException with connection timeout but when I create console app on .net framework everything works fine. Everything in the apps is the same.

Edit 1.
Proxy on server is disabled on server, Integrated Security=False not working too.
Maybe the issue is only sqlDependency class from System.Data.SqlClient for .netCore 3.1 Windows services ?

Anyone know why this situation occurs?

Comment: The connection is not completing an timing out after 30 seconds.  I need to see your connections string.  The connection string is either connecting to a different server or the credentials are failing.

Comment: Here is connection string which one is use on both apps                                         Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=123"

Comment: Fo real everything is the same but on .NetCore app connection cannot be stablish

Comment: I assume you are on a different machine with Net and Core.  Where is database?  Is it on same machine as the Net application?  A 30 seconds timeout usually means a proxy is being used a eventually the proxy isn't found after 30 seconds.  The proxy should be disabled.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The applications are on my computer and the server on my local network

Comment: Try setting Integrated Security = false (windows credentials).  See : http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/failed.htm

Comment: @jdweng it's still not working throw timeout on .netCore service

Comment: You should be using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (not System.Data.SqlClient).